# Konjunktiv II von "bringen" in der Vergangenheit

Tags: subjunctive, perfect-tense

Welche der folgenden Sätze sind grammatikalisch richtig?

> Es hörte sich an, als hätten Sie X mit Y in Verbindung gebracht.
>
> Es hörte sich an, als brachten Sie X mit Y in Verbindung.
>
> Es hörte sich an, als brächten Sie X mit Y in Verbindung.

Die erste Variante schien mir nach einigem Grübeln am richtigsten, doch habe ich mit der zweiten etwa intuitiv kein Problem. Gibt es Argumente dafür oder sind die unteren zwei gänzlich falsch?

Answer (score 4):

Alle Sätze sind (nach meinem persönlichen Sprachempfinden, Puristen mögen das anders sehen) grammatikalisch richtig. Bei ungebräuchlichen, als altmodisch oder geziert empfundenen Formen des Konjunktivs (*brächten*) möchte man diese Formen gerne vermeiden. Das kann man auf verschiedene Arten machen:

1) Ersatzform mit *würde*:

> Es hört sich an, als würden Sie X mit Y in Verbindung bringen.

2) Wechsel der Zeit:

> Es hörte sich an, als hätten Sie X mit Y in Verbindung gebracht.

3) Wechsel zum Indikativ:

> Es hörte sich an, als brachten Sie X mit Y in Verbindung.

Wahrscheinlich gibt es noch mehr Möglichkeiten, wenn man stärkere Umformulierungen zulässt. Welche Möglichkeit gewählt wird ist wohl eher Geschmackssache.

Answer (score 1):

bringen:

Konjunktiv 1

> Sie sagten, sie bringen etwas in Verbindung.

Konjunktiv 2

> Es hörte sich an, als brächten sie etwas in Verbindung.

brauchen:

Konjunktiv 1

> Sie sagten, sie brauchen etwas.

Konjunktiv 2

> Es hörte sich an, als bräuchten sie etwas.